# Cannot discover USB device port?

Tags: drivers, usb, udev, tty, serial-port

I am trying to find this a micro controller device that's plugged in with a USB to my computer and ideally I want open up the port that it's connected to. Problem is that I cannot find the device's name under /dev/tty*

When I run `lsusb` I get this

```
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 0557:2419 ATEN International Co., Ltd Virtual mouse/keyboard device
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 0557:7000 ATEN International Co., Ltd Hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 1366:0101 SEGGER J-Link PLUS
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0a5c:21e8 Broadcom Corp. BCM20702A0 Bluetooth 4.0
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 046d:c08b Logitech, Inc. G502 SE HERO Gaming Mouse
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 046d:c335 Logitech, Inc. G910 Orion Spectrum Mechanical Keyboard
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

The Device im looking for is
`Bus 001 Device 005: ID 1366:0101 SEGGER J-Link PLUS`

Also on boot I can see this information of the device that I used to create a udev rule for and running `sudo dmesg | grep usb`

```
[    3.569824] usb 1-4: new full-speed USB device number 5 using xhci_hcd
[    3.723556] usb 1-4: New USB device found, idVendor=1366, idProduct=0101, bcdDevice= 1.00
[    3.723569] usb 1-4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[    3.723576] usb 1-4: Product: J-Link
[    3.723581] usb 1-4: Manufacturer: SEGGER
[    3.723586] usb 1-4: SerialNumber: 000660015877
```

Then this is my udev rule

`SUBSYSTEM=="tty", ATTRS{idVendor}=="1366", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0101", ATTRS{serial}=="000660015877", SYMLINK+="segger"`

However it didn't work and I still can't find it as a tty device.
Also when running `udevadm monitor` and then plugging in the device I get this

```
KERNEL[896.791227] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-4 (usb)
KERNEL[896.792767] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-4/1-4:1.0 (usb)
KERNEL[896.792897] bind     /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-4 (usb)
UDEV  [896.800175] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-4 (usb)
UDEV  [896.803020] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-4/1-4:1.0 (usb)
UDEV  [896.811772] bind     /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-4 (usb)
```

Then I am aware of where the device is located and when I run `udevadm info /dev/bus/usb/001/008` this is the information that I get

```
P: /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-4
N: bus/usb/001/008
L: 0
E: DEVPATH=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-4
E: DEVNAME=/dev/bus/usb/001/008
E: DEVTYPE=usb_device
E: DRIVER=usb
E: PRODUCT=1366/101/100
E: TYPE=0/0/0
E: BUSNUM=001
E: DEVNUM=008
E: MAJOR=189
E: MINOR=7
E: SUBSYSTEM=usb
E: USEC_INITIALIZED=896799819
E: ID_VENDOR=SEGGER
E: ID_VENDOR_ENC=SEGGER
E: ID_VENDOR_ID=1366
E: ID_MODEL=J-Link
E: ID_MODEL_ENC=J-Link
E: ID_MODEL_ID=0101
E: ID_REVISION=0100
E: ID_SERIAL=SEGGER_J-Link_000660015877
E: ID_SERIAL_SHORT=000660015877
E: ID_BUS=usb
E: ID_USB_INTERFACES=:ffffff:
E: ID_VENDOR_FROM_DATABASE=SEGGER
E: ID_MODEL_FROM_DATABASE=J-Link PLUS
E: ID_PATH=pci-0000:00:14.0-usb-0:4
E: ID_PATH_TAG=pci-0000_00_14_0-usb-0_4
E: ID_FOR_SEAT=usb-pci-0000_00_14_0-usb-0_4
E: TAGS=:seat:
E: CURRENT_TAGS=:seat:
```

Currently this is the tty's that show up and ideally I would be looking for ttyUSB0 but that doesn't show up and nothing is pointing me to what tty it could be

`tty   tty10  tty13  tty16  tty19  tty21  tty24  tty27  tty3   tty32  tty35  tty38  tty40  tty43  tty46  tty49  tty51  tty54  tty57  tty6   tty62  tty8       ttyS0   ttyS11  ttyS14  ttyS17  ttyS2   ttyS22  ttyS25  ttyS28  ttyS30  ttyS5  ttyS8 tty0  tty11  tty14  tty17  tty2   tty22  tty25  tty28  tty30  tty33  tty36  tty39  tty41  tty44  tty47  tty5   tty52  tty55  tty58  tty60  tty63  tty9       ttyS1   ttyS12  ttyS15  ttyS18  ttyS20  ttyS23  ttyS26  ttyS29  ttyS31  ttyS6  ttyS9 tty1  tty12  tty15  tty18  tty20  tty23  tty26  tty29  tty31  tty34  tty37  tty4   tty42  tty45  tty48  tty50  tty53  tty56  tty59  tty61  tty7   ttyprintk  ttyS10  ttyS13  ttyS16  ttyS19  ttyS21  ttyS24  ttyS27  ttyS3   ttyS4   ttyS7`

Any direction would be very helpful, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can find the device name by watching `sudo journalctl --follow` as you connect your device. OR `ls -1 /dev >dev.before`, connect the device, wait 10 seconds, `ls -1 /dev >dev.after;diff dev.{before,after}`.

After you find the device name, `sudo journalctl  /dev/devicename` will show more info.

Comment: Will this allow me to access the port for development? My main problem is that im able to find where the device is located but not the serial port? Keep in mind that I don't know much about the serial ports so I'm not sure if it's entirely relevant.